# Execute API call until desirable response is returned

Tags: php

The process I am creating needs to send data to a soap service. I cannot proceed with my next action until I get a desirable response.

```
try {
    $return = $soapClient->__soapCall("BulkLoadContacts",array('parameter' => $params));

    foreach ($return as $r){
        $upload_id = $r;
    }

    $process_params = array(
        'ProcessID' => $upload_id,
    );
    $return = $soapClient->__soapCall("GetProcessStatus",array('parameter' => $process_params));
    var_dump($return);

}
catch(SoapFault $fault){
    $status = false;
}
```

In the above piece of code, I execute the `BulkLoadContacts` method. I then grab the `ProcessID` from the response.  Once I have that ID, I then make another call to get the status of the my process. The last dumper tells me the response of `GetProcessStatus`. The dumper looks like:

```
object(stdClass)#18 (1) {
  ["WSProcessStatus"]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (6) {
    ["ProcessID"]=>
    int(3313881)
    ["ListID"]=>
    int(268207)
    ["ProcessName"]=>
    string(20) "listrak_tempfile.txt"
    ["ProcessStartTime"]=>
    string(23) "2012-05-16T14:22:50.643"
    ["ProcessCompleteTime"]=>
    string(22) "2012-05-16T14:22:50.84"
    ["Status"]=>
    string(19) "ProcessingCompleted"
  }
}
```

The last item is `Status`. Only until the method returns with the value of "ProcessingCompleted" do I want to proceed. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Would a simple do-while be sufficient?

Comment: A do/while should do the trick.  But I'd recommend putting a delay in each loop, otherwise you'll be hammering the Soap server.  Also You probably want to specify a max number of tries.  You don't want to have your program stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @ben, could you post this as an answer so I can award you credit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A do/while should do the trick. But I'd recommend putting a delay in each loop, otherwise you'll be hammering the Soap server.

Also, you probably want to specify a max number of tries. You don't want to have your program stuck in an infinite loop.

```
try {
    $return = $soapClient->__soapCall("BulkLoadContacts",array('parameter' => $params));

    foreach ($return as $r){
        $upload_id = $r;
    }

    $attempts_remaining = 10;
    do {
        sleep(1);
        $process_params = array(
            'ProcessID' => $upload_id,
        );
        $return = $soapClient->__soapCall("GetProcessStatus",array('parameter' => $process_params));

        $attempts_remaining--;
    } while (($return->WSProcessStatus->Status != 'ProcessingCompleted') && ($attempts_remaining > 0));

    if($return->WSProcessStatus->Status == 'ProcessingCompleted') {
        //success
    }
    else {
        //timeout
    }


}
catch(SoapFault $fault){
    $status = false;
}
```